# Apple mach-o linker (id) error with C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I created a new project in **Xcode 5.0** to implement a Queue class as following:
I created a .h file called QueueArray.h and it contains the following:

```
#ifndef __Queue__QueueArray__
#define __Queue__QueueArray__

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class QueueArray
{
public:
    QueueArray(int cap);
    ~QueueArray();

    void Enqueue(T& val);
    T Dequeue(void);
    T GetFirst(void);
    T GetLast(void);
    bool IsEmpty(void);
    bool IsFull(void);
    void Clear(void);

private:
    T* data;
    int capacity, size, first, last;
};

#endif
```

and a .cpp file called QueueArray.cpp that contains the following:

```
#include "QueueArray.h"
using namespace std;

template <class T>
QueueArray<T>::QueueArray(int cap)
{
    capacity = cap;
    data = new T[capacity];
    size = 0;
    first = last = -1;
}

template <class T>
QueueArray<T>::~QueueArray(void)
{
    delete [] data;
}

template <class T>
void QueueArray<T>::Enqueue(T& el)
{
    if(IsFull() == true)
    {
        printf("\n Can't enqueue into a full queue!");
        return;
    }
    if(IsEmpty() == true)
        first = last = 0;
    else if(last == capacity-1)//if at the last entry
        last = 0; //wrap around to the first entry
    else
        last++;
    data[last] = el;
    size++;
}

template <class T>
T QueueArray<T>::Dequeue()
{
    if(IsEmpty() == true)
    {
        printf("\n Can't dequeue from an empty queue!");
        return -1;
    }
    T el = data[first];
    if(first == last) //if only one element in queue
        last = first = -1; //we'll get an empty queue
    else if(first == capacity-1) //if at the last entry
        first = 0; //wrap around to the first entry
    else //normal case
        first++;
    size--;
    return el;
}

template <class T>
T QueueArray<T>::GetFirst()
{
    return data[first];
}

template <class T>
T QueueArray<T>::GetLast()
{
    return data[last];
}

template <class T>
bool QueueArray<T>::IsEmpty(void)
{
    return size == 0;
}

template <class T>
bool QueueArray<T>::IsFull(void)
{
    return size == capacity;
}
```

and a main.cpp file that contains the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "QueueArray.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    QueueArray<int> q(100);
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        q.Enqueue(i);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        cout<<q.Dequeue()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run the project, a message appears saying "Build Failed" and here is a screenshot of the errors:

[image: Screenshot]

How to fix that?

Comment: Way too much code, not an Xcode question. Furthermore, the linker is `ld`, not `id`.

Comment: too much code to make it clear because I don't know where the problem is. 
You are right for the rest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to see the definition of the Template before using it.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html

There are more than one solution:

a. Move the definitions from .cpp file to the .h file

b. Use the `export` keyword **if your compiler supports**

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl-export-keyword.html

c. Add an inline declaration:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html

Comment: clang does not support exported templates

Comment: Yeah, i realized from an old SO post after googling. But, kept it in the answer for more generality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the template definitions in-line with their declarations. An easy solution to this is to rename `QueueArray.cpp` to something like `QueueArray_impl.h` and `#include` it from the bottom of `QueueArray.h`

```
#ifndef __Queue__QueueArray__
#define __Queue__QueueArray__

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class QueueArray
{
public:
    QueueArray(int cap);
    ~QueueArray();

    void Enqueue(T& val);
    T Dequeue(void);
    T GetFirst(void);
    T GetLast(void);
    bool IsEmpty(void);
    bool IsFull(void);
    void Clear(void);

private:
    T* data;
    int capacity, size, first, last;
};

#include "QueueArray_impl.h"

#endif
```